# How should I mathematically formulate correctly the following statements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number.
I want to create two sets.
Set 1:
I want to list every positive integer from 1 to $p$ in a set called $A$. 
For example if $p=7$, then $A$ = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
Is the following mathematically correct, or if not, how should I formulate it ? 
Let $A$ = {$k$, where $k ∈ Z+, k = 1$ to $p$}

Set 2:
I want to list every $(k, k+2)$ number pair in a set called $B$. 
For example if $p=7$, then $B$ = {(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6),(5,7),(6,8),(7,9)}
Is the following mathematically correct, or if not, how should I formulate it? 
Let $B$ = {$(k,k+2)$, where $k ∈ Z+, k = 1$ to $p$}

Thanks.

Comment: Rather than saying "$k=1$ to $p$" it is better to write $1\leq k\leq p$.  So, matching your notation otherwise I would have written as $\{k~:~k\in \Bbb Z^+,~1\leq k\leq p\}$.  That said, there is standard notation for your set $A$ and that is $[p]$ (*noting that in some contexts $[p]=\{1,2,3,\dots,p\}$ while in others it might have been preferred as $\{0,1,2,\dots,p-1\}$ but most times they are interchangeable, $[p]$ being used simply as the "quintessential $p$-element set"*)

Comment: As an aside, $p$ being prime seems entirely irrelevant to the questions.

Comment: Thank you for the help.